# How to do *dpkg-reconfigure dash* as bash automatically

Tags: ubuntu

I want to build a docker image from ubuntu image.
It is required to change the default sh from dash to bash manually.
(Because it require to install many rpm packages which contains bash scripts)

```
dpkg-reconfigure dash
```

Is there any method to let this action automatically without human behavior?

In my Dockerfile it maybe written as(Method 1)

```
RUN dpkg-reconfigure dash
```

I've tried another method(Method 2)

```
RUN ln -sf bash /bin/sh
```

But, both method can not work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make debconf only ask for high or critical questions[1].

Ex:

```
dpkg-reconfigure -p critical dash
```

dpkg-reconfigure will use default answer defined in debconf script. You can also use debconf-get-selections to pick up different answer for noninteractive installation[2].

1. https://wiki.debian.org/debconf
2. http://blog.nutsfactory.net/2008/03/06/noninteractive-dpkg-installation-on-debian-system/

Comment: If you want to see what's going on when runing dpkg-reconfigure
DEBCONF_DEBUG=developer dpkg-reconfigure -p critical dash

Comment: debconf-get-selections is missing. I can not found in http://packages.debian.org/wheezy/all/debconf/filelist.

Comment: I use `debconf-show dash` to get options.
`echo "dash dash/sh boolean false" | debconf-set-selections` and `DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive dpkg-reconfigure dash` to do non-interactive configuring.

Comment: @DanielYCLin if you added that as its own answer, I would upvote it.

Answer (score 42):

Pasting Daniel's comment as an answer here since it doesn't rely on default settings from `dpkg-reconfigure`.

To get options:

```
debconf-show dash
```

To set this particular option to `false`:

```
echo "dash dash/sh boolean false" | debconf-set-selections
```

and to actually reconfigure the package:

```
DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive dpkg-reconfigure dash
```

This worked for me from a Dockerfile:

```
# make /bin/sh symlink to bash instead of dash:
RUN echo "dash dash/sh boolean false" | debconf-set-selections
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive dpkg-reconfigure dash
```

Answer (score 4):

Through some trial & error and much assistance from others, this ansible statement does the same thing:

```yaml
# See "/var/cache/debconf/config.dat" for name of config item after changing manually
- name: aws-ssm ansible plugin fails if dash is the default shell
  ansible.builtin.debconf:
    name: dash/sh
    question: dash/sh
    value: false
    vtype: boolean
```

Answer (score 0):

You should instead patch those scripts to use `#!/bin/bash` instead of `#!/bin/sh`. Newer versions of Debian and Ubuntu no longer support using anything other than dash for `/bin/sh`.

Comment: Sure I will just patch this obscure extremely expensive commercial EDA tool that I didn't write...